# Report for failure records of batches

Tags: custom-reports

Can we create and run report which summaries all the errors in the various batches in Salesforce? We have so many records failing in various batches.

Thanks for your time.

Thanks,
Sanjana

Answer (score 0):

As far as batches failure is concerned, what you can do is:-

- create a custom object with fields to store the error message
- Refractor your code with a method to store the Error logs and insert to newly created object
- Do DML operation using

> Database.SaveResult[] Listname = Database.update(Updatelist, false);

- run For Loop for this list and execute your method

After the error record gets inserted, You can create a custom report and run it.

Hope it helps you.